# Get original Python type from type hint

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, type-hinting

I am using modern Python type hints as like `Tuple[int,...]`.
Somewhere I need to get the original Python type (`tuple`, `list`...) from given type hint variable. for example:

```
t = Tuple[int,...]

# Get tuple from t
```

Comment: type hinting is only useful for static code analysis. There is not much use besides this special case.

Comment: @Daniel: But when performing static code analysis, it'd sure be useful to have a convenient way to get `tuple` from the annotation `Tuple[int, float]`.

Comment: I think you're stuck with cruddy options like parsing `repr(t)`.

Comment: Proof that there is, and cannot be such a thing: consider the "hint type" `Union[Tuple, List]`. It does **not** corresponding to any real python type. Hence a function that takes hints to "real types" doesn't exists. QED.

Comment: @Bakuriu: A function that takes type hints to concrete types if they actually correspond to a concrete type could easily exist, though. For example, those type hints could just provide a `concrete_type` attribute. No such functionality seems to exist, though.

Comment: One possible way is to use ``__extra__`` attribute. If it is present, it works like this ``List[int].__extra__ == list``. Currently, this does not work with all types (e.g. not for ``Tuple``). Note, this is an undocumented internal feature and is subject to breakage without warning ;-) Also you should never modify ``__extra__``, otherwise things could break really badly.

Comment: Actually there is an `__origin__` attribute, but I would rather not to use private `__` fields.

Answer (score 2):

## Simple case : `Type[type, ...]` :

```py
import typing
from typing import Tuple, Optional
t = Tuple[int,...]

typing.get_origin(t)
>>> tuple

typing.get_args(t)
>>> (int, Ellipsis)
```

## Optional and nested : `Optional[Type[type, ...]]`

As `Optional[T]` is equivalent to `Union[T, None]` return is like an `Union`. Nested types are retrieved recursively the same way.

```py
t = Optional[Tuple[int,...]]

typing.get_origin(t)
>>> typing.Union

typing.get_args(t)
>>> (typing.Tuple[int, ...], NoneType)

typing.get_origin(typing.get_args(t)[0])
>>> tuple
```